# How can I reduce the optimality gap of the routing model's assignment by allow more time to search?

Tags: c#, routes, or-tools

I am solving a pick and delivery problem. I was testing OR-Tools to know how good it is by the following example:
 1. Two vehicles at same start, two pickup locations (one for each customer) that are actually the same point in terms of geolocation, two customers having the same geolocation too. 
 2. No demand or capacity, just a time dimension between points and constraints to satisfy pickup and delivery.
 3. The objective is to reduce the global span of the cumulative time
It's obvious that the optimal solution will use both vehicles, but it doesn't! I tried a lot of settings to make it escape from a local optima, but it still doesn't and doesn't even try to use the time at hand to reach a better solution and just finishes in a couple of seconds.

So, how can I force it to continue search even if it thinks that the solution at hand is enough?

BTW: I checked if my logic is correct by giving it the optimal route as an initial route, and when I do that, it uses it. It also, indicated that the objective value of the optimal route is less than the original route, so I guess there are no bugs in the code.

Comment: This question would be greatly improved with some code.

Comment: I thought about that, but I only want to know a way to extend search time; nothing specific to my problem.

Comment: You can set the parameter time_limit_ms in an object search_parameters and pass it to the solver.

I have a question, though: why is it obvious that the optimal solution will use both vehicles? Shouldn't it be more efficient for a single vehicle to go to the first pickup node, first delivery node, second pickup node and finally to the second delivery node?

Comment: Also, which local search metaheuristic are you using? I found that the OBJECTIVE_TABU_SEARCH yields a non-optimal solution very quickly (typically in a few seconds), regardless of how much time you allow it to take.

Comment: I tried extend the time limit, but it didn't work. I experimented with multiple meta-heuristics, and none of them worked, but I generally used Guided Local Search the most. It would be optimal to use the two vehicles because the goal is to minimize the max delivery time not the total distance covered by the vehicles, so 1 vehicle doing everything will extend the total time taken to deliver to both customers.